# Search on last word in a field using Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I'm using SphinxQL to prepare Sphinx searches (in fact part of a NOT operator) but am unable to do something that is pretty simple with Mysql: like '% Word'. I simply need to know when a specific word is the last one in the field/string but SphinxQL doesn't seem to lend itself to that.

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
Lazy Dog day afternoons
```

I'm essentially looking to search on

```
select  Description from idx_Table WHERE (MATCH('@(Description) Fox Dog (not like '% Dog'))
```

I get that the above is not proper SphinxQL at all but is essentially what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a field end modifier, so can specifically match the last word in the a field.

```
... WHERE MATCH('@(Description) Fox Dog$')
```

Will only get you matches where the last word is Dog. Use phrase marks if want the last two (or more!) words.

```
... WHERE MATCH('@(Description) "Fox Dog$ " ')
```

But there is still no assertions to say, match this, EXCEPT when it's the last word

```
... WHERE MATCH('@(Description) Fox Dog$ -Dog$')
```

would execute, may well be excluding 'valid' matches.

Comment: That is close enough, I can run the Dog$ one and then the Dog$ one and post-process. Thank you.